# Rolling counts and sums with different condi

Tags: r, optimization, group-by, data.table, rolling-computation

I have a data table of donations as below:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Payment_Method__c = sample(c("a","b","c"),100,replace = TRUE)
                  ,Contact_ID__c = sample(c(1:70),100,replace = TRUE)
                  ,Deceased.Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100)
                  ,Created.Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2005/01/01'), by="day"), 100)
                  ,Commitment_Date__c = sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100)
                  ,Cancellation_Date =sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100)
                  ,Opportunity_Type = sample(c("single","regular"),100,replace = TRUE)
                  ,GBPamount = sample(c(5,10,15,20),100,replace = TRUE)) 
DT[Opportunity_Type=="single" | Cancellation_Date < Commitment_Date__c, Cancellation_Date := NA]
DT[Deceased.Date < Commitment_Date__c | Deceased.Date < Cancellation_Date, Deceased.Date := NA]
```

For each month from 2000/01/01 to 2020/01/01 I need to calculate the number of contacts and the sum of GBPamount in certain groups:

- For each month only contacts where Created.Date is less than the last day
  of the month and Deceased.Date is either NA or later than the first
  day of the month should be considered
- For each month, the contact is classified as:

  - Regular_active - if the Commitment_Date__c of any donation of
    Opportunity_Type regular for this contact is before the first day of
    the month and Cancellation_Date is either NA or on or after the first day of
    the month
  - Regular_lapsed - if it is not regular_active and the
    Commitment_Date__c of any donation of Opportunity_Type regular for
    this Contact_ID__c is before the first day of the month and
    Cancellation_Date is also before the first day of the month
  - Single - if it is not regular_active and it is not regular_lapsed and
    the Commitment_Date__c of any donation of type single for this
    contact is before the first day of the month
  - Non-donor - if it is
    not regular_active, nor regular_lapsed nor single
- Additionally, for each month considered another classification for contacts is in place:

  - Existing - if Created.Date is before the FY of the month considered (FY is considered 1st April -- 31st March the following year)
  - New - if Created.Date is in the FY of the month considered

Then, for each month I need to calculate the number of contacts that have given new donation among each of the above groups, by Opportunity_Type (single/regular) and by Payment_Method__c:

- e.g among regular_active new contacts,

  - how many made a regular donation by payment method 'a'
  - how many made a single donation
- similar for regular_active existing, regular_lapsed new, etc.

I have a partial solution in place but my code is very inefficient and inflexible and I was wondering if there might be some more elegant way of handling this:

```
dates <- seq(floor_date(min(all[!is.na(Created.Date),Created.Date]),"month"),floor_date(max(all[!is.na(Created.Date),Created.Date]),"month"),"month") %m+% months(1) -1

   DT <- DT[month(Created.Date)<4, Created.FY:=year(Created.Date)-1]
   DT <- DT[month(Created.Date)>=4, Created.FY:=year(Created.Date)]    

#calculate number of donations in each group per contact: Single Regular_active, Regular

dt_list = lapply(X=dates, FUN = function(date){


 print(date)
  a <- DT[Commitment_Date__c < floor_date(date,"month") & Opportunity_Type == "Single" & ((Deceased.Date > Created.Date & Deceased.Date > floor_date(date,"month")) | is.na(Deceased.Date)),
          .(single = .N),
          by = list(Contact_ID__c)]
  a[,date:= date]
  a
})

single = rbindlist(dt_list)

colnames(DT)

dt_list = lapply(X=dates, FUN = function(date){



print(date)
  a <- DT[Commitment_Date__c < floor_date(date,"month") & Opportunity_Type == "regular" & ((Deceased.Date > Created.Date & Deceased.Date > floor_date(date,"month")) | is.na(Deceased.Date)),
          .(recurring = .N),
          by = list(Contact_ID__c)]
  a[,date:= date]
  a
})

regular = rbindlist(dt_list)

dt_list = lapply(X=dates, FUN = function(date){
print(date)
      a <- DT[Commitment_Date__c < floor_date(date,"month") & (Cancellation_Date__c >= floor_date(date,"month") | is.na(Cancellation_Date__c)) & Opportunity_Type == "regular" & ((Deceased.Date > Created.Date & Deceased.Date > floor_date(date,"month")) | is.na(Deceased.Date)),
              .(recurring_active = .N),
              by = list(Contact_ID__c)]
      a[,date:= date]
      a
    })

regular_active = as.data.table(rbindlist(dt_list))

#calculate how many contacts converted each month, for recurring and single separately, by payment method:
dt_list = lapply(X=dates, FUN = function(date){
  print(date)
  a <- DT[Commitment_Date__c >= floor_date(date,"month") & Commitment_Date__c <= date & Opportunity_Type == "regular" & ((Deceased.Date > Created.Date & Deceased.Date > floor_date(date,"month")) | is.na(Deceased.Date)),
          .(regular_created = .N,regular_created_sum = sum(GBPamount)),
          by = list(Contact_ID__c,Payment_Method__c)]
  a[,date:= date]
  a
})

regular_created <- as.data.table(rbindlist(dt_list))
regular_created1 <- as.data.table(dcast(regular_created,Contact_ID__c + date ~ Payment_Method__c, value.var = "regular_created"))
regular_created2 <- as.data.table(dcast(regular_created,Contact_ID__c + date ~ Payment_Method__c, value.var = "regular_created_sum"))
regular_created1 <- regular_created1[,c("Contact_ID__c","date","a","b","c")]
regular_created2 <- recurring_created2[,c("Contact_ID__c","date","a","b","c")]
setnames(regular_created1,c("a","b","c"),c("regular.a","regular.b","regular.c"))
setnames(regular_created2,c("a","b","c"),c("regular.a_sum","regular.b_sum","regular.c_sum"))
regular_created1[,c("regular.a","regular.b","regular.c")] <- nafill(regular_created1[,c("regular.a","regular.b","regular.c")],fill = 0)
regular_created2[,c("regular.a_sum","regular.b_sum","regular.c_sum")] <- nafill(regular_created2[,c("regular.a_sum","regular.b_sum","regular.c_sum")],fill = 0)
regular_created <- as.data.table(merge(regular_created1,regular_created2, by = c("Contact_ID__c","date")))

#then I merge all these tables by 'Contact_ID__c' and 'date' and run the code below for various combinations of conditions (number of single new donors converting to recurring donation by payment method a in example)

dt_list = lapply(X=dates, FUN = function(date){
  print(date)
  a <- DT[Created.Date <= date & ((date == Date_donations & single > 0 & regular == 0)) & (regular.a>0) & ((Deceased.Date > Created.Date & Deceased.Date > floor_date(date,"month")) | is.na(Deceased.Date)) & ((Created.FY == year(date) & month(date)>=4)|(Created.FY == year(date)-1 & month(date)<4)),
          .(single_new_to_regular_a = sum(`regular.a`), single_to_regular_a_sum = sum(`regular.a_sum`)),
          by = list(Country.of.Ownership)]
  a[,date:= date]
  a
})

single_new_to_regular_a = rbindlist(dt_list)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Confused by the statement "before the first day of the month". Do you simply mean NOT on the first day of a month? Also with "on or after the first day of the month" - isn't that any day of the month?

Comment: If your current inefficient solution produces correct answer, then it make sense to include it, so anyone can verify if their approach matches your expected results.

Comment: @MarianMinar The recurring donations can be cancelled before, during or after the month that is being considered. To put the confusing statements differently: "before the first day of the month" - not on the first day of a month and not on any day after the first day of the month (neither that month or subsequent ones); "on or after the first day of the month" - on any day from the first day of the month; could be during the month considered or any subsequent ones.

Comment: @jangorecki Thank you for your comment. I've added an overview of the current approach now.